# How to achieve multi-line output with formatting in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, formatting, multiline

I am experimenting with the following codepen.io trinket and trying to achieve multiline output with formatting for the JavaScript text that is returned in response to user-input.

For instance, if the user types "/engage" the following text is returned:

**"Follow the white rabbit. I want this to be the second line"**

The code is below. I would like the above text to:

a) be output on two separate lines with my being able to control the breaks between lines (like br in HTML)
b) allow some basic formatting - specifically to add bold formatting to the word "rabbit".
c) allow for changing the font size of "follow" to a larger font/or different style etc.

In short, I want to be able to add formatting (hyperlinks are also a key one) and can't find any direct documentation on this for useful reference. the \n works for line breaks, thank you @epascarello

I have tried various things but they all come up with errors.

**RELEVANT CODE**

```
submitForm.addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (input.value === "/clear") {
        clearCommand();
    } else if (input.value === "/list" || input.value === "help") {
        listAllCommands();
    } else if (input.value === "/connect") {
        goProgress();
    } else if (input.value === "/engage") {
        matrixEffect();
        clearCommand();
        textArea.value = "Follow the white rabbit. I want this to be the second line"
    } else {
        textArea.value +=
            "\nERROR: Unknown command! Type 'help' for list of commands.";
        input.value = "";
    }
    textArea.scrollTop = textArea.scrollHeight;
});
```

**CODEPEN ENTIRE SNIPPET**

https://codepen.io/damyco/pen/oyewjR

Comment: So use a line break just like you do in the else!? `'I like cheese.\nIt is good.\nSmile!'`

Comment: I think you should replace `if else if else if` with a `switch`

Comment: where is documentation I can find on this? As I also need the formatting. Could you post an answer epascarello so I can accept it, that also deals with the BOLD and FONT SIZE. Another answer said something about not using line breaks and using white-space: pre-wrap; instead. Not sure how

Comment: @Jeremy Thille, could you post a solution with switch, but also perhaps dealing with my bold/style/hyperlink formatting insertion issues?

Comment: Ah, I saw you are using a textarea. As far as I know, it does not support formatting, just raw text.

Comment: that's useful - so how would I go about (easily) allowing for formatting, using my existing code?